# open transaction issue in ssis after crashed visual studio

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I am creating one SSIS package inside that I am truncating one big table and then insert records into that. While in the process the visual studio/ssdt is hanged due to unknown reasons and I have to kill that through task manager in windows.

Now my destination table is get locked and I cannot see records in that. I used dbcc opentran and found that transaction is still open.

How can I close this transaction or session and what is best practice in this case because I am not doing anything wrong just visual studio was crashed and i just kill that.

Comment: It sounds like this open transaction may have been blocking your package in VS, which is why it was hanging.  In any case use the command in SSMS `kill <SPID>` - where SPID is the id of the transaction that you are trying to kill

Comment: Actually vs creates that transaction and never rollback and commit that.

Answer (score 1):

Have your DBA find the hanging SPID and kill it.

Comment: Is it possible that if I restart system where vs is installed then locking would be gone?

Comment: It's very unlikely, but I can't say it's not possible.

Comment: @hieko restarting the system where you are running VS will do nothing to the transaction.  It is already disconnected.  If it's not already rolling back, you'll need to kill it as noted in this answer

Comment: Is there anything I can do to prevent this issue?

Comment: There might be.  It would first involve finding out what the "unknown reasons" are for the process hanging.